# When use a Supervised Classification on a mosaic dataset, one image does not get classified

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, classification

I am working in ArcGIS Pro. I am trying to run a supervised classification on a mosaic datasets. The inputs to the mosaic dataset are: 4 non-geographically adjacent raster datasets; 3 of those are orthomosaiscs have been combined with LIDAR data using the "Composite Bands" tool, one is just an orthomosaic. Each individual raster dataset appears normal when added to the map. After combining all of them into the mosaic dataset, they appear funky. Sometimes, one of the datasets is all black; if I play with the symbology the other datasets lose their visability.

I ended up running a supervised classification using the classification wizard and training data from all 4 datasets. 3 of the 4 datasets looked like they were reasonably classified. The dataset that usually appears all black when added to the mosaic dataset is classified as one class.

The multispectral data from the problem raster dataset was processed in a different way than the other 3.

How do I get this to work? I have already calculated statistics and pyramids.